Setup SCSS with Next JS 14
I want to know a better way to set up SCSS. I followed the Next docs but my styles are taking a second to load, in development and production. There aren't many articles/blogs/YouTube videos that cover that subject
Here is my implementation of the next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require("path");
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")],
  },
});

and my styles are set as follows:
src
|----app
|     |___global.scss
|     |
|     |___page(route)
|             |_____styles.module.scss
|
|----scss
      |__mmixins & other variables 

